# Why can't I use a generic type to implement a non-generic signature

Tags: java, generics

I'm a little confused by the Java compiler.

I've got an interface that has a method signature with "Object":

```
public interface Bean {
    public void setCreated(final Object created);
}
```

I would like to implement it using a generic:

```
public class BeanImpl<T extends Object> implements Bean{
        private T created;

        public void setCreated(final T created){
            this.created = (T)created;
        }
}
```

However, this produces a compiler error:

```
Name clash: The method setCreated(T) of type BeanImpl<T> has the same erasure as setCreated(Object) of type Bean but does not override it
```

Given that by definition, `T` is an Object (), why does the compiler not allow me to make this construct?  Trying to mark it is `@Override` just produces an error msg that the method doesn't actually override a supertype.  It is almost as though the compiler does not understand/see that `T` is actually an Object.

Comment: It's because `foo(String)` isn't overriding `foo(Object)`, it's **overloading** it.

Comment: Right.  Try putting the "@Override" annotation on your `setCreated()` method and you'll see the problem right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that was allowed, someone could then potentially create

```
public class Child extends BeanImpl<Integer> {
    public void setCreated(Integer created){
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and

```
Bean bean = new Child();
bean.setCreate(new NotAnInteger());
```

and type safety would break. You have to satisfy the interface.

Comment: Correct. You can, however, tighten the return value.

Comment: Fair enough.  Hadn't thought it through fully that way.